# Offline Message

Tags: connection, message, hotspot

I have been thinking about this for a while. We know some games can be played through hotspots. While playing the games we can even send message. An example is the Doodle army mini militia. I was thinking of building an app where only my friends can send messages at a short distance if they are connected to the hotspot.

I did an experiment today. I set up a hotspot. I connected two phones to the same hotspot with the internet. (three phones. one phone only to open the hotspot. The other two just to connect to the hotspot) So, now I tried to send a message to the other phone through what's app. I sent the message through the second phone to the third phone. The message was successfully sent to the third phone. We knew this would work. It is a very simple process. Now my question is below.

When I disconnected the data connection on the first phone. Remember the hotspot is still on. The only thing is that there is no internet. Now I sent a message again from the second phone to the third phone. This time the message did not go through. I knew the message would not go through. The question is why does there have to be a proper data connection with the internet for the message to go through? Well, there is already a connection where phones have the path to send the message. We also know some games can send messages while connected to hotspots without the internet.

Answer (score 0):

No, your assumption regarding sending of messages through Whatsapp is completely wrong.

When you send a message from one device to another device, the message is first send to Whatsapp Databases. It will be stored there unless the device which you've sent to has got an internet connection (There's a limit for the storage on database, like 1 year or something.)

**The thing is that Whatsapp is not connecting devices directly, they are being connected together under Whatsapp , Whatsapp is the Intermediate in the Process of messaging.**

Comment: In Games like doodle Army Mini militia, while Setting up offline multiplayer , direct messages can be sent over network, But that's not the same in case of Social Medias Like Whatsapp,Telegram etc.